# webscraping: extracting url from xpath in html using python: airbnb listings

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to extract urls for listings from a city page in AirBnb, using python 3 libraries. I am familiar with how to scrape simpler websites with Beautifulsoup and requests libraries.

url: 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Denver--CO--United-States/homes'

[element in the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUQtr.png)

If I inspect the element of a link on the page (in Chrome), I get:

```
xpath: "//*[@id="listing-9770909"]/div[2]/a"
selector: "listing-9770909 > div._v72lrv > a"
```

My attempts:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Denver--CO--United-States/homes'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'listing'})
```

attempt 2:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get(url)
root = html.fromstring(page.content)
tree = root.getroottree()
result = root.xpath('//div[@id="listing-9770909"]/div[2]/a')
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Neither of these returns anything. What I need to be able to extract is the url for the page link. Any ideas?

Comment: Inspecting the DOM isn't enough, you need to view-source and verify that it's there when the page loads. Because neither of those libraries has a javascript engine.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the links, first you have to make sure that the urls to the links exists in the page source. For this you can search with any of the listing ids in the page source(ctrl+u if you are using google chrome,mozilla firefox). If the urls exist in the page source you can directly scrape them using xpath in the response text of the listing page. Here the above listing page of Airbnb is not having the links in the page source, so the page might be sending requests to some other pages(usually json requests). You can find out those requests and send requests to those pages and get the required data.
Please comment if you have any doubt regarding this.

Comment: Thanks! I can now see the source code in Chrome (this is what I've been able to pull with requests.get() and soup), and indeed the listing ids are not there. I think I need to do what you say next: find these json requests (somewhere in that <meta_content=...> block?) and make the requests. Could you explain that step?

Comment: I should mention I HAVE found an xpath string which works for returning the class handles for all links on a page (that is, it works in the javascript terminal on Chrome developer tools on the page): '//*[contains(@href, "rooms")]'